# Does boost::container support C++11 initializer lists?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, initializer-list

At the Boost.Container website we can read this:

> Boost.Container does not support initializer lists when constructing or assigning containers but it will support it for compilers with initialized-list support. (...)

Excuse me if I'm just dumb, but I don't really know how to read it. Does it mean that it will do that in unpredicted future, or should it work with conforming compilers right now?

I've tested it on GCC 4.7 and ICC 13.0, neither works, but I believe I could've missed something pretty important, like proper preprocessor definition?

Comment: Maybe not preprocessor definition, but the `-std=c++11` compiler flag?

Comment: @ChristianRau I've tested it alongside `std::vector`, so nope, not that.

Comment: I guess you got it right.: "it will do that in unpredicted future", and only for C++11 compilers (reasonably)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Boost.Container from v1.52 currently doesn't have any initializer_list constructors. Unfortunately the only source I can give you is the fact I manually searched through the entire containers library source.

Comment: `+1` for "manually searched through the entire containers library source"